# Doing a line count in build.gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a file in my build folder that have information about dependency problems.

**I want to count the number of lines in a report (a file) of dependency issues**

I have the following pseudo-code:

```
dependencyCheckAnalyze.doLast {
    // check if there are bad dependencies
    if ('build/reports/dependency-check-report.csv'.linecount > 1) { 
        // line 1 is the title (ie. all dependency problems comes on next lines)
        // do stuff regarding dependency issues
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to call `java.io.BufferedReader.readLine()` in a while loop until it returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some basic Groovy feature, you can easily count number of lines in a String:

```
task countLines{
    doLast{
        println "Number of lines: " + file('build.gradle').text.readLines().size()

    }
}
```

Comment: This will unnecessarily read the whole file into memory. Possibly not an issue but definitely not best practice

Comment: In this context : "a file that have information about dependency problems", there will be no memory/performance issue, I made assumption that there cannot be enough dependency issues in the project to make some harm to memory ;)   but I agree with you, for other kind of files, streaming/buffering would be a better approach.